# Extention to save original page state and restore to original state

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, bfcache

I have a requirement to create a firefox addon where i need to save the state of a dynamically rendered page along with all the events.

While interacting with page. the user might make multiple catalog selections using select option,check boxes swatches etc.

I need to restore the page  to it's original state or a state in between without the page reload. I don't have control over the webpage hence a addon requirement.

I have tried using jquery clone and it does not work. After spending loads of time.
i think if i can push the page to firefox bfcache and pop the saved state from 
cache. this problem would be solved. in one of the stackoverflow query someone had demonstrated this using http://www.twmagic.com/misc/cache-nocache.html

How would i go about using this approach or any other ? any pointer , links to sample would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What code have you already tried? Please *[edit] the question* to include your source code. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  If we are going to try to verify our solution works for you it is MUCH easier to do so if we have your code to start from rather than having to make it all up. Without such code there is less incentive to find an answer for you.

Comment: Something like this addon? https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/unmht/ It allows you to save a complete webpage into one file.